# Kotlin ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey

Tags: java, sockets, server, kotlin, client

I'm creating a Client-Server Chat application in Kotlin. The Client is a Android Client and in commuicates with the server over sockets.
I have a MessageObject with different constructors to make different types of the Message.

MessageObject.kt

```
package message

import com.cyens.chat.securechat.message.Type
import com.cyens.chat.securechat.user.User
import java.io.Serializable
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MessageObject(var type: Type) : Serializable {

    val created = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date())
    var message: String? = null
        private set
    var receiver: String? = null
        private set
    var username: String? = null
        private set
    var password: String? = null
        private set
    var friend: User? = null
        private set
    var friends: ArrayList<User>? = null
        private set
    var publicKey: PublicKey? = null
        private set
    var chats: ArrayList<MessageObject>? = null
        private set
    var version: String? = null
        private set
    var key: ByteArray? = null
        private set
    var read: Boolean = false
    var answer: Int = 0

    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
    }

    constructor(type: Type, publicKey: PublicKey) : this(type) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey
    }

    constructor(type: Type, key: ByteArray) : this(type){
        this.key = key
    }

    constructor(type: Type, username: String, password: String, version: String) : this(type) {
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
        this.version = version
    }

    constructor(type: Type, message: String, receiver: String) : this(type) {
        this.message = message
        this.receiver = receiver
    }

    constructor(type: Type, answer: Int) : this(type) {
        this.answer = answer
    }

    constructor(type: Type, s: String) : this(type) {
        this.message = s
    }

    constructor(type: Type, user: User) : this(type){
        this.friend = user
    }

    constructor(type: Type, list: ArrayList<Any>) : this(type) {
        if (type == Type.CHATS)
            this.chats = list as ArrayList<MessageObject>
        else
            this.friends = list as ArrayList<User>
    }

}
```

The first two messages sent are not encrypted and after that every MessageObject is encrypted.

Function for sending the message:

```
fun send(messageObject: MessageObject){
        async {
            val secretKey = Keys.secretKey
            if (secretKey == null){
                outputStream.writeObject(messageObject)
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("SecretKey not null")
                AES256.encrypt(messageObject, outputStream)
            }
            outputStream.flush()
        }
    }
```

When I now receiv the message on the Server I am checking if the object is encrypted or not:

```
messageObject = if (inputStream.readObject() is MessageObject) {
                    inputStream.readObject() as MessageObject
                } else
                    RSACipher.decrypt(inputStream, Keys.privateKey)
```

A ClassNotFoundException is thrown on inputStream.readObject()
(I'm not even using conscrypt so where is this comming from?)
The Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:686)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
            at server.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.kt:61)
```

My methods for encrypting and decrypting

```
fun encrypt(message: MessageObject, outStream: OutputStream, publicKey: PublicKey) {
// Create cipher
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
val sealedObject = SealedObject(message, cipher)

// Wrap the output stream
val cos = CipherOutputStream(outStream, cipher)
val outputStream = ObjectOutputStream(cos)
outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject)
outputStream.close()
}

fun decrypt(inStream: InputStream, privateKey: PrivateKey): MessageObject {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)

    val cipherInputStream = CipherInputStream(inStream, cipher)
    val inputStream = ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream)
    val sealedObject: SealedObject
    sealedObject = inputStream.readObject() as SealedObject

    return sealedObject.getObject(cipher) as MessageObject
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance and sorry for my english.
Ludtwigk